# while loop bash script

Tags: bash, shell

i have a text file contains following information:

```
/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/L2_LAC_OC/A2006001071000.L2_LAC_OC.x.hdf:2006:365
/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/L2_LAC_OC/A2006001084000.L2_LAC_OC.x.hdf:2013:011
/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/L2_LAC_OC/A2006001084500.L2_LAC_OC.x.hdf:2005:365
....
```

I want to echo $f1 where $f2 is "2013" and $f3 is "011". i am using following script but its echoing all. what am i doing wrong here?

```
file=/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/input/all_file_list.txt
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
    [ "$f2" = "2013" ] || [ "$f3" = "011" ]
    echo $f1
done < "$file"
```

any solution?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the comparison inside an `if` sentence and use `&&` instead of `||`, like:

```
file=/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/input/all_file_list.txt
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
    if [ "$f2" = "2013" ] && [ "$f3" = "011" ]; then
        echo $f1
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: thank you very much.this solution works; i am very happy about that. I am greedy ;). now I am little bit more ambitious.. what if, I want to add ... "$f3 = 001 to 007". what would be the correct syntax for that?? thank you in advance....

Comment: @neel: Use `-gt` and `-lt` to compare numbers, like:`[ "$f3" -gt "000" ] && [ "$f3" -lt "008" ]`

Comment: Grate, Awesome....Thank you very mush for the effort; i really appreciate it but u know, nothing is enough for me. :). ######### ok, now the next help I need is: in my "$f2" column I have data ranged from "2006" to "2013" (year) and in "$f3" column, from "000" to "365" (day of year). I need to find a efficient looping method which will echo "$f1" based on year wise weekly condition in different text file name like 2006_01.txt, 2006_52, 2007_03.txt, 2007_52.txt and so...... any help, I might get?

Comment: ... i was able to automate part of my need but still i have to find out how i can deal the weeks.. ***I Have put my code in the comment section, bellow***

Comment: @neel: That can be considered a different question. You should better create a new one for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect the test to the action

```
[[ $f2 == 2013 && $f3 == 011 ]] && echo $f1
```

or

```
if [ "$f2" = "2013" ] && [ "$f3" = "011" ]; then
    echo $f1
fi
```

What you are doing now is performing the test commands and ignoring the exit status. So the echo command does indeed execute for every line.

Answer (score 1):

You are `echo`-ing `$f1` always, regardless of whether the line matched. Try this instead:

```
[[ "${f2}" == "2013" ]] && [[ "${f3}" == "011" ]] && echo "${f1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This fits Awk's processing model hand in glove.

```
awk -F : '$2 == "2013" && $3 == "011" { print $1 }'  /media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/input/all_file_list.txt
```

If you want a regex instead, that's done like `$3 ~ /^00[1-7]$/` or you could do a numeric comparison `$3 > 0 && $3 <= 7`.

Answer (score 0):

... as mentioned above, i was able to automate part of my need; a little more help required, here is the code....

```
file=/media/Arc/eo_archive_test/MODIS/input/all_file_list.txt
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
for year in "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013"
do
[[ $f2 == $year ]] 
for doy in "001" "002" "003" "004" "005" "006" "007" # here we need some automation; seeking help
do
[[ $f3 == $doy ]] && echo $f1 >> test.txt
done
done
done < "$file"
```